# Forcing a JPopupMenu to disable hover effects on its owner JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, hover, jtable, jpopupmenu

When i right click on a JTable in a JFrame I show a JPopupMenu. If I left this JPopupMenu shown as it is and moved with the mouse to the JTable I can still hover on its rows.

This is not the default behavior of Windows applications. In normal case if a popup menu appears in a program it blocks any hover actions on the popup owner window.

Can i do the same thing in Java ?

Comment: I believe this is normal windows behavior for a pop up or tool tip.  What your describing is the behavior of a modal dialog.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: This is wrong. Just open Windows Notepad, right click inside it to show the Cut/Copy/Paste pop-up. Leave it as it as then move with the mouse on Notepad's menubar, and try to hover on the menubar buttons ... No hover effect will occur. But in Java applications you can still hover on such JMenubar controls.

Comment: if you want to disable menu effects you will need to set mouse listeners on higher level containers, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this problem is to set an instance variable in one of your GUI elements to flag whether or not to enable hover events. I have shown below how this may work, but it's not in its complete form, you will also need to re-enable hover when the JPopupMenu is dismissed, and also check the state of the `ENABLE_HOVER` field before firing hover effects.

```
public MyTable extends JTable {

    private boolean ENABLE_HOVER = true;

    public MyTable() {
    ...
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        ...
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (isRightClick(e)) {
                setHoverEnabled(false);
                showJPopupMenu();
            }
        }
    });
    }

    protected void setHoverEnabled(final boolean hover) {
        this.ENABLE_HOVER = hover;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there are many other controls other than the JTable that the user can hover on. The idea is that i use personalized tooltips on all the controls, so hovering on the controls shows those tips in addition to the hover effect, making it look so bad while the popup is shown. I need something like when showing the popup: myFrame.setEnabled( false ); ... Something like that, but this will disable the popup too.

Answer (score 1):

Another method which may be better suited to disabling multitudes of however enabled elements is to intercept the events at the glass pane. An example of how this might work is shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane). Be warned though if your interface is already built it may require significant re-jigging of your component classes.

You will need to intercept all events at the glass pane, if hover is enabled (no popup menu shown) you would pass the event to the appropriate component. Otherwise if hover is disabled and the MouseEvent occurred over the JPopupMenu is passed only to the JPopupMenu.